# I am getting a strange error when I try to execute a wsf script from C#. Am I doing it right?

Tags: wsh

I am having a tough time trying to figure out this issue I am having when trying to execute a wsf script from my C# application, and am hoping some one can shed some light on this strange error.

Assume that I am on a Windows 2012 server. I run this command from the command line:
*C:\windows\Syswow64\cscript.exe C:\myscript.wsf //job:Job2*

This script executes just as intended with no issues. I have to use the 32-bit cscript because reasons. Now flash forward to my C# application which does the following:

```
processInfo.FileName = "C:\\windows\\Syswow64\\cscript.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = TaskPath + " " + Parameters;
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
...
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
int errorLevel = 0;

using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
{
    using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data == null)
            {
                outputWaitHandle.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                output.AppendLine(e.Data);
            }
        };
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data == null)
            {
                errorWaitHandle.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                error.AppendLine(e.Data);
            }
        };


        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();
        errorWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        outputWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        errorLevel = process.ExitCode;
    }              
}
```

I would like to note at this point that this code has worked with many other scripts that we have tried. The I try to execute this script. the TaskPath = "C:\myscript.wsf" and Parameters = "//job:Job2". When trying this, I get the following error:

**C:\myscript.wsf(100, 50) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'CDate'**

Normally, I would think that this must mean that there is something wrong with the script, but the script runs just fine on the command line as I described above. What could be different? Is it possible that since the script is being executed by the C# app, it is taking on some weird default time localization? I just don't quite understand where the difference could be coming from and am hoping you guys can help me; thanks inadvance! :)

**Update**
So I have been able to determine (I think) that the C# application has nothing to do with it. The C# application was being run under a different user than the one that I was running it on from the command line. There's no user specific code being ran in the script so might anyone know a reason that a different user may cause the error?

Comment: CDate is a VBScript function which leads me to believe cscript somehow doesn't select the right engine. Maybe you can specify the engine manually cf. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx 
Edit: nevermind, it clearly says in the error that it's the VBScript runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look into this. I would think though that if I'm calling cscript from both the command line and the C# application it would select the same engine, but apparently not.

Comment: Like I said, the error says it's the VBScript engine so it's not that. It might be that the current culture of the app is not the same as the operating system; if you have some idea of what the culture should be you can check by examining CultureInfo.CurrentCulture at runtime.

Comment: I should take some time before replying, there's a pattern here... the culture of your application doesn't matter because you're starting a different process, and there's no way to affect its culture that I know of. I got no other ideas.

Comment: Maybe, I will check the CurrentCulture, but I can't imagine that whatever the default is wouldn't be correct. There's not too much in any of the scripts that is localization specific, but I will still check. Thanks :)